# ccsprite texture rect changes based on parent scaling?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d 2.2, and am experiencing the following:

I have a sprite added as a child to a CCNode.  The sprite's anchor point is 0,0.  The CCNode's anchor point is 0,0.  I've got a CCNode with an anchor point of 0.5,0.5 and in it I add a child with the following rect:   0,363,165,231).

I then add that CCNode as a child to another CCNode with an anchor point of 0,0...

All is well..  Looks perfect.

I scale that CCNode down to 0.5

All of a sudden, I see at the top of my sprite, garbage from the texture that is not part of it's texture rect.

Why in the world does scaling down a CCNode change the texture coordinates?!

Note, if the CCNode has an anchor point of 0,0 this doesn't happen.  Only when its 0.5, 0.5...

Comment: I don't think it's clear from your description which node is in which node. However, it sounds like because you have a node with anchor point of 0.5,0.5, it is getting added in the wrong place. Think of it as the middle of one node is touching the bottom left hand corner of the other node, so when you scale, the scaling is correct, but the positions are different.

Comment: But its not a matter of the position being wrong.  The position is right, there is literally garbage around the edges of the sprite after scaling, and that garbage is surrounding pixels from the texture file.  That garbage is not there when the scale is 1.0, as soon as I change it to 0.5, then the garbage appears....  So, my question is, why in the world would the texture rect coordinates be different based on scaling?

Comment: if you could add some code, then I can have a look for you if you're interested.